# Subtlety about an integral and its primitive

Tags: integration, continuity, trigonometric-integrals

I stumbled over a paper mentioning another paper, which gives an example of a subtle situation in integral theory (the example should be given in

> Jeffrey, D.J. ; Rich, A.D.: The Evaluation of Trigonome- tric Integrals Avoiding Spurious Discontinuities. In: ACM
>   Transactions on Mathematical Software 20 (1994), Nr. 1, S. 124–135)

where I don't have any access to.).

The integral is given as:

$$ I:=\int \frac{3}{5-4\,\cos(x)} \mathrm{d} x $$

Simple symbolical calculation (and ignoring the poles in $\mathbb{R}$) yields:

$$ I = 2 \, \arctan\left( 3 \, \tan\left(\frac{x}{2} \right) \right) + C.$$

Ploting this with maple gives:

[image: Plot of antiderivative neglecting the local constants]

The subtlety of this example is that the $\tan\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)$ substitution creates singularities, though the integrant itself is perfectly continuous. Therefore, we'd expect at least a continuous function as an antiderivative in theory.

As I am aware that I need to introduce local constants for getting all possible antiderivates locally as with the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$  in $\mathbb{R}_{-}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{+}$, I am convinced that I can get a continuous function.

> My question now is: Assume that I have chosen all the contants properly, so that I "glue" the parts together in a continuous or even continuously differentialbe way. Is there any way to write down the formula for the antiderivate avoiding infinite many cases?

EDIT: As the answer is already given as a comment, I might ask if there is a generic way how to avoid these troubles where choosing different local constants can be omitted? It seems as if one needs to choose different brances of the tangent at different places. Can this be done symbolically and automatically without worrying at all?

Comment: It seems to me that you could simply add $2\pi \lfloor \frac{x-\pi}{2\pi}\rfloor$ to get a continuous function.

Comment: @Gribouillis Alright. Thank you. Might be hard to see differentiability then (which can also be expected) though (which was not the original question).

Comment: Differentiability will be very easy because if $f^\prime$ has the same limit on the left and on the right of a point and the function is continuous, then it is differentiable at that point. It is a consequence of the mean value theorem.

Comment: @Gribouillis Thanks. That answered my question. Little addition: $2 \cdot \pi \cdot \lfloor \frac{x-\pi}{2\,\pi} \rfloor + 2 \cdot \pi$ will shift the function to the origin in $0$. Thanks again!